# Webview is not responding some times "Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring"

Tags: android, webview

Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring

> 01-18 20:30:48.725  30673-30673/com.packname.debug W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
>   01-18 20:30:48.725  30673-30673/com.packname.debug W/AwContents﹕ onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
>   01-18 20:30:48.735  30673-15614/com.packname.debug D/startTraficSt :﹕ 2525554070
>   01-18 20:30:48.845  30673-15614/com.packname.debug D/oneByteTimeMillis :﹕ 106
>   01-18 20:30:48.975  30673-30673/com.packname.debug W/BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 30673
>   01-18 20:30:49.205   30673-5751/com.packname.debug E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:raw_channel.cc(341)] Invalid number of platform handles received
>   01-18 20:30:49.205   30673-5751/com.packname.debug E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:channel.cc(307)] RawChannel read error (received bad message)
>   01-18 20:30:49.205   30673-5735/com.packname.debug W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:proxy_message_pipe_endpoint.cc(50)] Failed to write enqueue message to channel
>   01-18 20:30:49.205   30673-5735/com.packname.debug W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:proxy_message_pipe_endpoint.cc(50)] Failed to write enqueue message to channel
>   01-18 20:30:49.205   30673-5735/com.packname.debug W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:channel.cc(315)] RawChannel write error